# Change name of sheet in export to excel

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I have export to excel code which gets data from database then create dynamic gridview and then export that data to excel.

Problem is that i it is taking sheet name same as i mentioned filename. So how do i change sheet name

Here is code i am using

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "SummaryReport " + Helper.GetTime(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString() + ".xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
gridView.DataSource = ReportExecutor.ReportExportData(startDate, endDate);
gridView.DataBind();
//This will change the header background color
gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); //
//This will apply style to gridview header cells
for (int index = 0; index < gridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; index++)
{
    gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Style.Add("background-color", "#778899"); //Light Slate Gray
    gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Style.Add("foreground-color", "#ffffff"); // White
}
int index2 = 1;
//This will apply style to alternate rows
foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gridView.Rows)
{                   
    gridViewRow.BackColor = Color.White;
    if (index2 <= gridView.Rows.Count)
    {
        if (index2 % 2 != 0)
        {
            for (int index3 = 0; index3 < gridViewRow.Cells.Count; index3++)
            {
                gridViewRow.Cells[index3].Style.Add("background-color", "#e6e6fa");// Lavender
            }
        }
    }
    index2++;
}
gridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
////  Response.Write(style);
Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Presently you are getting `Helper.GetTime(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString()` name right?

Comment: No i am getting filename and sheet name as SummaryReport+Date and Time

Comment: So what do you want to change then?

Comment: As you can see from code i mentioned filename so it should work only for filename not for sheetname name.. i means i mentioned filename as 'SummaryReport+Date and Time' which is working for filename but problom is it is renaming sheet name with filename name too... And i want sheet name different

Comment: May be this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086185/export-to-excel-and-change-sheet-name

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't change the sheet name of an excel file generated from setting Response content type as excel. Refer accepted answer of [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803511/how-to-set-the-sheet-name-for-a-c-sharp-generated-excel-spreadsheet) and from [ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1929658.aspx?Download+excel+file+change+the+sheet+name)

You could also take a look at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample), which has an option to edit sheetnames in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with StringWriter. You may have to re-open and then rename the sheet once it's successfully written using the StringWriter.

Otherwise, you have to use an alternate method to create the Excel. Here's an example

[Export GridView to multiple Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632782/export-gridview-to-multiple-excel-sheet)